# Getting Type of expression which stored in string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime

I have a Dictionary - stored names of variables with their types.
Also, I have a string with expression. 
Is there any way to get Type of this expression?

Example:

- dictionary

  - `"x" : List<DateTime>`
  - `"a" : int`
- string : `"x[a+5]"`
- expected result: `DateTime`

In addition, I also know all included namespaces.

This task is little part of global task: I trying to write web implementation for Workflow designer. The problem with "Assign" activity. I have strings with expression for left and right parts, but if left part not just variable name then I have a problem with detecting their type("Assign" activity requires types of arguments).

Comment: have u tried : `typeof`(takes a type name (which you specify at compile time)), or `GetType` (gets the runtime type of an instance),  or `is` (returns true if an instance is in the inheritance tree) !

Comment: I have no instance, I just have a string with expression. so typeof, GetType and "is" have no sense in my case, it will always string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution via linq dynamic (can be installed from nuget)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public Type GetExpressionType(string expression, IDictionary<string, Type> variables)
{
  var types = new List<ParameterExpression>();
  foreach (var varType in variables)
    types.Add(Expression.Parameter(varType.Value, varType.Key));
  var lamda = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(types.ToArray(), null, expression);
  return lamda.ReturnType;
}
```